How to resolve "AADSTS90099: The application has not been authorized in the tenant"?
I work in a multi-tenant environment, where we have an administrator-account in one tenant (the partner tenant), and use that account to do work in other tenants (customer tenants). We have access to the customer tenant via GDAP (previously DAP).
When I try to use the Microsoft Graph Command Line Tools (Connect-MgGraph) to connect to the customer tenant, I get the following error message.

AADSTS90099: The application '{appId}' ({appName}) has not been authorized in the tenant '{tenant}'. Applications must be authorized to access the external tenant before partner delegated administrators can use them.

I have found a reference for this error code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/reference-error-codes
It says to do the following:

Provide pre-consent or execute the appropriate Partner Center API to authorize the application.

But I can't really figure out how to do that. How can we authorize this application for use?
